# set unique constraint for a column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, codeigniter

I have a sql table and I am storing a json encoded values in one column. Now I want to set unique constraint for one of the values of that column. Is it possible ?[image: Please refer the below picture of my table]

```
@AlexCollette 
select version(); 
5.7.32-cll-lve

 CREATE TABLE `sale` (
 `sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sale_code` longtext,
 `buyer` longtext,
 `guest_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `product_details` longtext,
 `shipping_address` longtext,
 `vat` longtext,
 `vat_percent` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shipping` longtext,
 `payment_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_status` longtext,
 `payment_details` longtext,
 `payment_timestamp` longtext,
 `grand_total` longtext,
 `sale_datetime` longtext,
 `delivary_datetime` longtext,
 `delivery_status` longtext,
 `viewed` longtext,
 `verify_payment_details` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=344 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: can you elaborate this further  : "Now I want to set unique constraint for one of the values of that column"

Comment: Will the json values always have the same format?

Comment: not quite, if you are using JSON which is not a native datatype in database, setting any constraint on them is not a wise move. but I do lack experience about this kind of problem though.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  say what the actual constraint you want is.  show output of `show create table yourmysterytablename` (as text, not an image please)

Comment: @SikanderNawaz thanks for your response!  Here I have a column named payment_details, in that column I have a value named mihpayid . I want to make that value as unique one.. No duplicales are allowed for that value

Comment: @AlexCollette Yes  json have the same format

Comment: and do you want to allow values that aren't json or don't have a mihpayid?

Comment: I just want to prevent the duplicate entries for mihpayid

Comment: I think your options are to either break the JSON into seperate columns and put unique constraints on the relevant ones, or to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger to parse and validate it. Past that, the easiest thing may be to do the validation clientside, if thats an option.

Comment: I don't know if that means you do want to allow values that aren't json.  I don't know if that means you do want to allow json values with no myhpayid.  Please say.  Also please say what `select version();` shows and output of `show create table yourmysterytablename` (as text)

Comment: @AlexCollette No I can't break the json format as it is interconnected with others important process in the project

Comment: @AlexCollette I have updated the details you wanted in my question summary.. please check

Comment: You might wish to redesign that table schema and factor in that particular value( `mihpayid` ) as a separate column - you cannot set a column as unique by only a small piece of data from each record.

Comment: Why not use a normalized table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what the value is.  You cannot create an index directly on JSON in older versions of MySQL.  But, you can create a generated column and use that:

```
alter table sale add column mihpayid text generated always as
    (payment_details ->> '$.mihpayid') stored;

create unique index unq_sale_mihpayid on sale(mihpayid);
```